# Does the touch command only modify the timestamp of the file or the content as well?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have some files that I modified months ago and I want them to show up now as having the current datey.

By running something like

```
$ touch *.txt or
$ touch .jpg
```

Will that modify only the timestamp for those files, right? or do some other bits get modified in those files as well?

Comment: You might want to consider specifying the `touch -c` option where you specify wildcards: it prevents new files from being created. Without it, `touch *.ext` where no files match the wildcard, will create a real file literally called `*.ext`.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

`Update the access and modification times of each FILE to the current time.`

It neither knows about, nor cares, what is actually inside the file.